# PHP regex parsing - splitting tokens in my own language. Is there a better way?

Tags: php, string, parsing

I am creating my own language.

The goal is to "compile" it to PHP or Javascript, and, ultimately, to interpret and run it on the same language, to make it look like a "middle-level" language.

Right now, I'm focusing on the aspect of interpreting it in PHP and run it.

At the moment, I'm using regex to split the string and extract the multiple tokens.

This is the regex I have:

```
/\:((?:cons@(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(?:"(?:(?:\\\\)+"|[^"]|(?:\r\n|\r|\n))*")))|(?:[a-z]+(?:@[a-z]+)?|\^?[\~\&](?:[a-z]+|\d+|\-1)))/g
```

This is quite hard to read and maintain, even though it works.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is an example of the code for my language:

```
:define:&0:factorial
    :param:~0:static
    :case
        :lower@equal:cons@1
    :case:end
    :scope
        :return:cons@1
    :scope:end
    :scope
        :define:~0:static
        :define:~1:static
        :require:static
        :call:static@sub:^~0:~1 :store:~0
        :call:&-1:~0 :store:~1
        :call:static@sum:^~0:~1 :store:~0
        :return:~0
    :scope:end
:define:end
```

This defines a recursive function to calculate the factorial (not so well written, that isn't important).

The goal is to get what is **after** the `:`, including the `@`. `:static@sub` is a whole token, saving it without the `:`.

Everything is the same, except for the token `:cons`, which can take a value after. The value is a numerical value (`integer` or `float`, called `static` or `dynamic` in the language, respectively) or a string, which must start and end with `"`, supporting escaping like `\"`. Multi-line strings aren't supported.

Variables are the ones with `~0`, using `^` before will get the value to the above `:scope`.

Functions are similar, being used `&0` instead and `&-1` points to the current function (no need for `^&-1` here).

Said this, Is there a better way to get the tokens?

Here you can see it in action: http://regex101.com/r/nF7oF9/2

Comment: Is there a better way?  [Yes! Lex & Yacc](http://memphis.compilertools.net/interpreter.html).

Comment: @bishop Thank you for the suggestion. The idea is to run the language in PHP and Javascript. I don't think it is possible to run such a thing in PHP or Javascript. I will include the goal of the language.

Comment: @bishop I made the edit required. The suggestion you gave me could be in another stage for the "compilation" to PHP or Javascript (and in a more advanced stage to other languages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Update] To issue the pattern being complicated and maintainability, you can split it using [PCRE_EXTENDED](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), and [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.comments.php):

```
preg_match('/
  # read constant (?)
  \:((?:cons@(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|
  # read a string (?)
  (?:"(?:(?:\\\\)+"|[^"]|(?:\r\n|\r|\n))*")))|
  # read an identifier (?)
  (?:[a-z]+(?:@[a-z]+)?|
  # read whatever 
  \^?[\~\&](?:[a-z]+|\d+|\-1)))
  /gx
', $input)
```

Beware that all space are ignored, except under certain conditions (`\n` is normally "safe").

---

Now, if you want to pimp you lexer and parser, then read that:

What does (f)lex [GNU equivalent of LEX] is simply let you pass a list of regexp, and eventually a "group". You can also try [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) and [PHP Target Runtime](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets) to get the work done.

As for you request, I've made a lexer in the past, following the principle of FLEX. The idea is to cycle through the regexp like FLEX does:

```
$regexp = [reg1 => STRING, reg2 => ID, reg3 => WS];
$input = ...;
$tokens = [];
while ($input) {
  $best = null;
  $k = null;
  for ($regexp as $re => $kind) {
    if (preg_match($re, $input, $match)) {
      $best = $match[0];
      $k = $kind;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (null === $best) {
    throw new Exception("could not analyze input, invalid token");
  }

  $tokens[] = ['kind' => $kind, 'value' => $best];

  $input = substr($input, strlen($best)); // move.
}
```

Since FLEX and Yacc/Bison integrates, the usual pattern is to read until next token (that is, they don't do a loop that read all input before parsing).

The `$regexp` array can be anything, I expected it to be a `"regexp" => "kind"` key/value, but you can also an array like that:

```
$regexp = [['reg' => '...', 'kind' => STRING], ...]
```

You can also enable/disable regexp using groups (like FLEX groups works): for example, consider the following code:

```
class Foobar {
  const FOOBAR = "arg";
  function x() {...}  
}
```

There is no need to activate the string regexp until you need to read an expression (here, the expression is what come after the "="). And there is no need to activate the `class` identifier when you are actually in a `class`.

FLEX's group permits to read comments, using a first regexp, activating some group that would ignore other regexp, until some matches is done (like "`*/`").

Note that this approach is a naïve approach: a lexer like FLEX will actually generate an automaton, which use different state to represent your need (the regexp is itself an automaton).

This use an algorithm of packed indexes or something alike (I used the naïve "for each" because I did not understand the algorithm enough) which is memory and speed efficient.

As I said, it was something I made in the past - something like 6/7 years ago.

- It was on Windows.
- It was not particularly quick (well it is *O(N²)* because of the two loops).
- I think also that PHP was compiling the regexp each times. Now that I do Java, I use the Pattern implementation which compile the regexp once, and let you reuse it. I don't know PHP does the same by first looking into a regexp cache if there was already a compiled regexp.
- I was using `preg_match` with an offset, to avoid doing the `substr($input, ...)` at the end.

You should try to use the ANTLR3 PHP Code Generation Target, since the ANTLR grammar editor is pretty easy to use, and you will have a really more readable/maintainable code :)

Comment: Looking in the "evil" critic way, you suggest that I split 1 regex for a giant loop with the same regex that is repeated over and over again and hurt performance a lot? Now, looking on the "good guy" critic way, you suggest me to make a full lexer/parser with class definitions and everything to make it more maintainable and more optimizable? Your idea is great, but using `/*` as a comment, is what I want to avoid. I am thinking about using comment blocks (with the regex I made, you can type anything, anywhere you wish and it will be out, which is a **REALLY COOL** feature).

Comment: The loop apart, you'll still have to rerun the regexp several times (unless `preg_match_all` works for you) to split you input into tokens.

Comment: @NoDataFound Actually, `preg_split` with some parameters works perfectly. The regex is splited into parts: `(?:cons@(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(?:"(?:(?:\\\\)+"|[^"])*")))` takes the token `:cons@` and then you either put a `"string"` or a number, like `1` or `5.1`. The part `(?:[a-z]+(?:@[a-z]+)?|\^?[\~\&](?:[a-z]+|\d+|\-1)))` takes off a function, token, delimiter, operator, variable and all the other stuff. `:^~0` (variable on the above `:scope`), `:call` (calls a function), `:static@sub` (`module@method`), `:&0` (function `0` on the current scope), `:&factorial` (function `factorial`) all match that

Comment: That's where doing Java for years hurt my PHP knowledge :) I assume you used the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag ?

Comment: That flag isn't enough, since I don't need empty lines. Using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` does the job. I am going to use parts of your code, to analise and reject all the parts that are or aren't meant to exist. I'm going to start by implementing this in Javascript (my ssd died and bye bye lots of stuff I need).